# Restore a SQL Server 2000 backup on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2012

I have got following error message while restoring a backup from SQL Server 2000 to the latest version. I do not know the old version, now I am using SQL Server 2012 (11.0.3128.0).

The error message is:

> Msg 3169, Level 16, State 1, Server FF101, Line 1
>   The database was backed up on a server running version 8.00.0760. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 11.00.3128. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.

Comment: _“The database was backed up on a server running version 8.00.0760. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 11.00.3128.”_

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You are trying to restore a SQL Server 2000 database on SQL Server 2012. This is not supported.

You will need to restore your database on an instance of SQL Server 2005, 2008 or 2008 R2 first, then back it up from there, then restore the new backup on SQL Server 2012. [Microsoft explains this here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012/).

Comment: Is there any way to restore it directly on SQL 2012

Comment: @Johnny_D No. Download an eval ([here's a link for 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8850)), install a new named instance, restore your database, back it up, then uninstall the eval.

Comment: Here's a script that among other things automates the restore-backup cycle you have to perform: https://gist.github.com/timabell/d43b21f889bd9dada355 (skip to `proc #upgradeBackupFile`)

Comment: I owe you a drink, wonder why Microsoft didn't bother with such a simple statement !

Comment: Link directly from Microsoft Technet blog with step-by-step guide: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012/