# Moving database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2012, database-migration

I am trying to back up and restore a database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012. I know that the ideal method would be to use SQL Server 2005 or another program as an intercessor; however, I don't have access to any versions of this. So my question is, has anyone had any experience with any software similar that I could use as a middle agent to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore a SQL Server 2000 backup on SQL Server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788624/restore-a-sql-server-2000-backup-on-sql-server-2012)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any software that can act as an intercessor. SQL Server's database format is the definition of proprietary. You'll need to install an instance of SQL Server - temporarily - that lies somewhere between 2000 and 2012, in order to upgrade the database there, then back it up and restore it to 2012. There is no other path.

You don't have access to any intermediate versions? Sure you do. You can download the evaluation edition of SQL Server 2008 R2, and it will work for 180 days, which should be plenty of time to restore your database, increase the compatibility level, and then back it up again.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8158