# SQL Server Database restore from an older Server version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000, database-restore

I have a database backup file (`*.bak`) which seems to have been created with SQL Server 2000 (v8.00.0760) and I want to restore it under SQL Server 2012 (v11.00.3128).

That fails because SQL Server Management Studio tells me that this version is incompatible and that I have to recover the backup with a server compatible version.

Is it somehow possible to restore the backup under SQL Server 2012?

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: You have the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788624/restore-a-sql-server-2000-backup-on-sql-server-2012. What you can also do is use a 3rd party tool to compare and synchronize a SQl Server 2000 and SQl Server 2012 db

Answer (score 2):

In one step you can't restore backup from SQL 2000 in SQL 2012. The best supported option would be to restore this database on SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008, then back it up again and restore this new backup on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012.aspx