# Data migration MS SQL - MySQL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, migration

I've got a database files [here.](http://www.tiro-it.pl/migration/SKK.rar) It's a MS SQL database (I think 2005). I need to do a migration to MySQL. But my problem is to read the data from this database. I'm not experienced in migration, so sorry if my question is not very ambitious. I think I'd like to write a short program in C# to read data and then copy to another database system. Am I correct ? Or does anybody know any freeware tool to do it ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: you go to ur sql click on export option in sql format then import it. and done~

Comment: @vico: I'd -1 if it were possible. `ur`? If you're too busy to type out the other two letters, then you're too busy to be on this site.

Comment: My problem is to read the data from the given link. This is not my database. This is a file obtained from my client.

Comment: well if you didn't make your question so unclear and makes people download huge random files out of nowhere.. take EKOlog's as answer, too bad your client seems to removed the file extension to make the process fun for you : )

Comment: Yes. My question wasn't very clear. Now I know what to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MySQL Workbench** has ability to migrate between MS SQL Server and MySQL.

You probably have backup of database in zip file. First of all, **restore** it to Sql Server, because Workbench must connect to live database.

MySQL Workbench could be downloaded from here:
http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/

Comment: Yes. This a backup. But how to restore it ?

Comment: you open up your own running server management program connecting to a server and click backup, google for full details.

Comment: Download Sql Server Express if You don't have from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx. Restore instruction for Sql Server is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx

Comment: ok, I understand.  Now I've got a message: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 8.00.2039. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 11.00.3128. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
'
It seems that I should install an earlier version of SQL Server and restore the database.

Comment: Sql Server 2000 database backup needs at most Sql Server 2008 R2 version. Use solution from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788705/663364)