# I need to restore SQL Server 2000 backup to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sqldb

I have SQL Server 2000 database backups with me. And I need to restore them to SQL Server 2012.

Can you tell me the best approach to do it?

Comment: There is no direct way to do this - SQL Server 2012 does **NO LONGER** support SQL Server 2000 backups. You need an intermediate step - restore your SQL Server 2000 databases to SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2, then take new backups, and restore those to SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported. First you need to restore the db to sql 2005 or sql 2008 then take backup and restore it to sql 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You should've done some research before starting a new thread on SO, the reason for me to say this is that this question has already been asked on SO in a different context, but the solution has been clearly explained. Follow the answer that has been given at this link ([Restore a SQL Server 2000 backup on SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788624/restore-a-sql-server-2000-backup-on-sql-server-2012))

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Looks like our activities were on the same time, else I would've not answered. Thanks for the tip though!